# Have ip address and wifi connection on mint 17 but no internet connection?

Tags: networking

I have an ip address but no server found on browsers. Could be related to having been in hibernate mode? Tried disconnecting, turning router off etc. - no good. Can anyone help with how I might go about diagnosing the problem, I'm at a complete loss, thankyou

Answer (score 1):

It is fixed - it was actually due to my VPN killswitch detecting something wrong and turning my internet off. Thanks for assistance.

Comment: Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

What does

```
route -n
```

and

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

show?

Comment: kernel IP routing table

Comment: Destination  0.0.0.0 192.168.1.0 Gateway 192.168.1.1 0.0.0.0 Genmask 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 Flas ug u metric 0 9 Ref 0 0 Use Iface 0 wlan0 0 wlan0

Comment: # Generated by NetworkManager

Comment: I'm not sure if your formatting is messed up but is looks like you have no dns set. Try putting http://216.58.217.46 in a browser, if that works but doing http://google.com doesn't try adding the name servers to /etc/resolv.conf echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: Thanks kindly - that ip does work but/etc/resolv.conf results in permission denied??

Comment: You can either edit /etc/resolv.conf as root or if sudo is enabled you can do sudo echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf I would also look at settings in Network Manager that allow the dns to be set because I think next time it starts its going to blow etc/resolv away again.

Comment: I don't understand how to run as root. Sudo /etc/resolv.conf results sudo command not found, /etc/resolv.conf results permission denied

Comment: And now trying ip addresses in the browser gets nothing

Comment: Using terminal to ping ips now gets operation denied

Comment: From a terminal type su - and the administrator password you chose when you installed your system. From there you should be able to edit /etc/resolv.conf. However it seems at a minimum you have got a messed up default route now. So as I said before I would investigate the settings in Network manager so that you are getting both dns, a default route and an ip address.

Comment: Running as su still won't permit me access to /etc/resolv.conf. What should I be looking for in network manager? Under ipv4 settings for the connection I want I have additional dns servers 8.8.8.8 no additional search domains and no dhcp client I'd?